# Display average disk performance over time

Tags: linux, redhat

I am new to Linux and am looking for the command to show

A. View disk Performance

B. View avg disk performance over time.

so far I have come up with iostat, and iostat 1 which should refresh every second. 
But I'm not sure if this is the best method.

Comment: You definitely want to familiarize yourself with the goodies in the Linux [/proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) directory: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8381

Comment: That is actually a life saver, thanks Foggy.

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

iotop will monitor the i/o and read out.
iostat will generate a report of the stats every few seconds, this is the best method I have found for any others that have the same question.